# How to get the rendered/displayed size of a scaled image/frame in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I need to get the width and height of an image within a frame.  Both the frame and image use the `Scale` property instead of the `Offset` property to set the size.  I have an `UIAspectRatioConstraint` on the frame that the image is in.  Everything scales with the screen size just fine.

However, I need to be able to get the current width/height of the image (or the frame) so that I can perform some math functions in order to move a marker over the image to a specific position (X, Y).  I cannot get the size of the image/frame, and therefore cannot update the position.

Is there a way to get the currently rendered width of an image or frame that is using the `Scale` size options with the `UIAspectRatioConstraint`?

I'm sleepy.  I hope this makes sense...

My current math for getting a position on another image that uses `Offset` instead of `Size` is:

```
local _x = (_miniMapImageSize.X.Offset / _worldCenterSize.X) * (_playerPos.X - _worldCenterPos.X) + (_miniMapFrameSize.X.Offset / 2)
local _y = (_miniMapImageSize.Y.Offset / _worldCenterSize.Z) * (_playerPos.Z - _worldCenterPos.Z) + (_miniMapFrameSize.Y.Offset / 2)
```

Which gives me the player position within my mini-map.  But that doesn't scale.  The actual map does, and I need to position the player's marker on that map as well.

**Work-Around**

For now (for anyone else looking for a solution), I have created a work-around.  I now specify my actual image size:

```
local _mapSize = Vector2.new(814, 659)
```

Then I use the screen width and height to decide if I need to scale based off the x-axis or the y-axis.  (Scale my math formula, not the image.)

```
if (_mouse.ViewSizeX / _mouse.ViewSizeY) - (_mapSize.X / _mapSize.Y) <= 0  then
    -- If the width of the screen is at the same or smaller ratio with the height of the screen
    -- then calculate the new size based off the width
    local _smallerByPercent = (_mouse.ViewSizeX * 0.9) / _mapSize.X

    _mapWidth = _mapSize.X * _smallerByPercent
    mapHeight = _mapSize.Y * _smallerByPercent
else
    local _smallerByPercent = (_mouse.ViewSizeY * 0.9) / _mapSize.Y

    _mapWidth = _mapSize.X * _smallerByPercent
    _mapHeight = _mapSize.Y * _smallerByPercent
end
```

After that, I can create the position for my marker on my map.

```
_x = ((_mapWidth / _worldCenterSize.X) * (_playerPos.X - _worldCenterPos.X)) * -1
_y = ((_mapHeight / _worldCenterSize.Z) * (_playerPos.Z - _worldCenterPos.Z)) * -1

_mapCharacterArrow.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, _x, 0.5, _y)
```

Now my marker is able to be placed where my character is within the larger map opened when I press "M".

**HOWEVER**

I would still love to know of a way to get the rendered/displayed image size...  I was trying to make it to where I did not have to enter the image size into the script manually.  I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there is a property of most GUI elements called `AbsoluteSize`.  This is the actual display size of the element, no matter what it is scaled to.  (It is not that it stays the same when scaled, but it changes as it is scaled to give you the new size.)

With this, I was able to re-write my code to:

```
local _x = (_mapImageSize.X / _worldCenterSize.X) * (_playerPos.X - _worldCenterPos.X) * -1
local _y = (_mapImageSize.Y / _worldCenterSize.Z) * (_playerPos.Z - _worldCenterPos.Z) * -1

_mapCharacterArrow.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, _x, 0.5, _y)
```

Where `_mapImageSize = [my map image].AbsoluteSize`.

Much better than before.